# Gstreamer Process finished with exit code 132 on OSX with Hello World example

Tags: macos, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0, python-gstreamer

When I run the [Hello World tutorial](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/hello-world.html?gi-language=python) for the Gstreamers python API I get the following error:

```
GST_DEBUG=3 python tutorial_1.py
0:00:01.787091000 98337 0x7fde78071920 ERROR              gldisplay gstgldisplay_cocoa.m:171:gst_gl_display_cocoa_setup_nsapp: Custom NSApp initialization failed
0:00:01.787178000 98337 0x7fde78071920 ERROR                glutils gstglutils.c:229:gst_gl_element_propagate_display_context:<sink> Could not get GL display connection
0:00:01.788032000 98337 0x7fde78071920 WARN                 playbin gstplaybin2.c:4757:autoplug_select_cb:<playbin0> Could not activate sink glimagesink
0:00:01.792032000 98337 0x7fde78071920 FIXME           videodecoder gstvideodecoder.c:1052:gst_video_decoder_drain_out:<vp8dec0> Sub-class should implement drain()
0:00:01.859639000 98337 0x7fde78071980 FIXME           videodecoder gstvideodecoder.c:1052:gst_video_decoder_drain_out:<vp8dec0> Sub-class should implement drain()
zsh: illegal hardware instruction  GST_DEBUG=3 python tutorial_1.py
```

But when I run a Gstreamer command in terminal that serves essentially the same purpose the window opens correctly with no issues:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v playbin uri=https://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/media/sintel_trailer-480p.webm
```

Looking for a solution or a push in right direction to resolve this.

Environment:

- Hardware:

  - Model Name:    MacBook Pro
  - Model Identifier:  MacBookPro13,3
  - Processor Name:    Quad-Core Intel Core i7
  - Processor Speed:   2,7 GHz
- OS:

  - System Version:    macOS 11.6 (20G165)
  - Kernel Version:    Darwin 20.6.0
- GStreamer 1.18.4
- pygobject                 3.42.0
- python                    3.9.7

Code from the tutorial:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

import gi

gi.require_version('GLib', '2.0')
gi.require_version('GObject', '2.0')
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')

from gi.repository import Gst, GObject, GLib

pipeline = None
bus = None
message = None

# initialize GStreamer
Gst.init(sys.argv[1:])

# build the pipeline
pipeline = Gst.parse_launch(
    "playbin uri=https://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/media/sintel_trailer-480p.webm"
)

# start playing
pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)

# wait until EOS or error
bus = pipeline.get_bus()
msg = bus.timed_pop_filtered(
    Gst.CLOCK_TIME_NONE,
    Gst.MessageType.ERROR | Gst.MessageType.EOS
)

# free resources
pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is likely due to some requirements related to OpenGL on MacOS. Please note that in your example the `playbin` will try to open some OpenGL window to display the video inside. For an additional information please visit [this](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=790242) link.

The following is a simple example how to solve that problem in C++ using the [hello world](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/hello-world.html?gi-language=c) app:

```
#include <gst/gst.h>

#include <thread>

#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::thread t([&]{
    GstElement *pipeline;
    GstBus *bus;
    GstMessage *msg;

    /* Initialize GStreamer */
    gst_init(&argc, &argv);

    /* Build the pipeline */
    pipeline =
      gst_parse_launch
      ("playbin uri=https://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/media/sintel_trailer-480p.webm",
      NULL);

    /* Start playing */
    gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

    /* Wait until error or EOS */
    bus = gst_element_get_bus(pipeline);
    msg = gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered(
        bus, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE,
        static_cast<GstMessageType>(GST_MESSAGE_ERROR | GST_MESSAGE_EOS));

    /* Free resources */
    if (msg != NULL)
      gst_message_unref(msg);
    gst_object_unref(bus);
    gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
    gst_object_unref(pipeline);
  });
  CFRunLoopRun();
  t.join();
  return 0;
}
```

Building and running:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++17  -ggdb -O0  gst.cpp $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0) -framework CoreFoundation
$ ./a.out
```

Answer (score 0):

The window can only be created on a GMainLoop. Check out https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/streaming.html?gi-language=c

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).